# Can GST tax input credits be claimed for Meals and Entertainment which are 100% deductible for income purposes?

Tags: canada, tax-deduction, canada-revenue-agency, gst

Typical meals-and-entertainment operating expenses for business are limited to a 50% deductible towards *income* calculation. There are exceptions. The rules listed by the CRA allow higher percentage to be deducted under certain conditions, for instance the limit is removed for an all-employees end of year dinner [Food, Beverages and Entertainment Expenses, section ¶9](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/publications/it518r/archived-food-beverages-entertainment-expenses.html#P48_3894).

In the documentation for *input tax credits* (ITCs) for GST, for the case of most businesses (not a charitable org, nor public institution, etc) it would seem that it's always 50% of the expense's tax paid that can be credited from an eligible business dinner expense ([CRA ITC eligibility](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/gst-hst-businesses/complete-file-input-tax-credit/calculate-eligibility-percentage.html#eligibilitymeal) ).

It would seem, logically, that the same percentage applies for the same meal expense in both revenue and ITC calculation. But, the ITC docs explicitly mention different percentages for long-haul trucker meals, but nothing about the other meal exception cases. So, max 50% ITC deduction for all business meals?